# How does Kotlin achieve type-safety by eliminating checked exceptions?

Tags: kotlin, exception, type-safety

I am a newbie to Kotlin programming. While going through the advantages of Kotlin over Java I came across this claim that by avoiding checked exceptions Kotlin achieves type safety. Also I do not understand how the exception handled with an empty catch block harms type-safety(I read it on a blog)?
Can it be explained with an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By itself, removing checked exceptions doesn't increase type safety. Kotlin's claim of improved type safety comes from the other features and idioms it introduces to replace checked exceptions.

In Kotlin, exceptions are not intended to be used for recoverable failures. They're only there to handle bugs and logic errors.

> As a rule of thumb, you should not be catching exceptions in general Kotlin code.
> [...]
> Use exceptions for logic errors, type-safe results for everything else. Don’t use exceptions as a work-around to sneak a result value out of a function.
>
> https://elizarov.medium.com/kotlin-and-exceptions-8062f589d07

The "type-safe results" referred to above are things like [sealed classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/sealed-classes.html), which provide a very controlled way to enumerate the possible types that a function can return. For example, you could have a sealed class with one implementation for a successful result and other implementations for each of the possible types of failure.

> If there’s a single error condition and you are only interested in success or failure of the operation without any details, then prefer using `null` to indicate a failure. If there are multiple error conditions, then create a sealed class hierarchy to represent various results of your function. Kotlin has all those needs covered by design, including a powerful `when` expression.
>
> https://elizarov.medium.com/kotlin-and-exceptions-8062f589d07

Comment: In my experience, while the above _may_ be a valid goal, it's not reachable.  Anyone using the standard library, or other existing libraries, will be faced with exceptions that need handling: network time-outs, connection failures, file errors, parsing failures, and other non-preventable situations that shouldn't crash the program.  And although I can understand why Kotlin doesn't _require_ every exception to be caught, I don't understand why it prevents you even _seeing_ what exceptions could occur.  (It's not a theoretical problem; I've had production crashes from overlooking an exception.)

Comment: I've suggested before two changes that I think would make Kotlin much safer: 1) Indicate in the editor any uncaught exceptions that a function call could generate; and 2) Infer a `@Throws` annotation, if not specified.  (After all, the compiler can tell what exceptions are possible in many cases, even if currently hides that.)  Neither change would break any existing code, but they'd make it much easier to avoid many types of failure, and give developers the information they need to write safer code.